# Powershell CSV to Excel in UTF-8

Tags: powershell, utf-8, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

Editing the question with new findings.

- SQL query results saved in to CSV. This CSV perfectly maintains special characters
- CSV to Excel. Excel doesn't maintain special characters when opened via Excel app by double clicking the file
- Excel does work perfectly maintaining special characters by opening a fresh Excel app and then browsing the above mentioned excel file using 'Data'->'From Text'

---

I'm exporting SQL results to a temporary CSV file which contains special characters. CSV file is created with no issues still maintaining special characters due to the use of UTF-8 format.

However when I try to create an excel workbook with the contents of CSV it messes up the special characters. How can I maintain UTF-8 format when creating the excel workbook?

```
$sqlresults  = Invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance $AppServerInstance -Database $databaseName -ApplicationIntent "ReadOnly" -Credential $Cred -InputFile $inputFile -Variable $dateValues -Verbose
$sqlresults | Export-Csv -path $temporaryCsvFile -Encoding UTF8 -noTypeInformation # Export to CSV temporarily

$excelObject = New-Object -comObject Excel.Application
$excelObject.Visible = $false 

$workbookObject = $excelObject.Workbooks.Open($temporaryCsvFile)
```

Comment: Use UTF-8 w/ BOM for Excel to read UTF-8-encoded files properly.

Comment: @MarkTolonen can you please explain what you mean by BOM? Thanks

Comment: Can you try to replace :  `-Encoding UTF8` by `-Encoding Default`.

Comment: @JPBlanc As I said, CSV file is excellent by using Encoding UTF8. I just need to know what to include for the $excelObject.Workbooks to make the excel file in UTF-8 format

Comment: Have you tried using the great module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel). You don't even need an installed Excel to use it.

Comment: The utf8 file should have a bom.  I made a workboot with ® in it and it worked for me.  What characters aren't working?

Comment: @js2010 can you please tell me how to include a bom in powershell code? I'm a newbie. I have no issues with the CSV file as it is already in utf-8. Just can't get the excel file to save as utf-8, thus not retaining special characters

Comment: @user2574948 just change the `-Encoding` parameter of `Export-CSV` to `utf8BOM`.

Comment: @paxz no luck. I get the below error - Export-Csv : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "utf8BOM" does not belong to the set
"Unicode,UTF7,UTF8,ASCII,UTF32,BigEndianUnicode,Default,OEM" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an
argument that is in the set and then try the command again.

Comment: @user2574948 that's because `utf0BOM` is only available in PS 7.x - if you are still using an older version, you may want to upgrade.

Comment: @user2574948 powershell 5.1 `export-csv -encoding utf8` already includes the bom.  This is not the problem.  I haven't been able to reproduce any problem.

Comment: Are you sure the exported CSV indeed has those special characters? (open in notepad to look). Is your `$inputFile` you use in the SQL command UTF8 encoded? You could optionally also append switch `-UseCulture` to the Export-Csv cmdlet. With that, when double-clicking the csv file on a machine with the same regional settings, Excel should open it no problem.

Comment: It could also be your version of Excel.  I have 365.  I'd like to see some of the special characters.

Comment: @Paxz Unfortunately we are in a controlled environment and cannot upgrade to PS 7.x

Comment: @js2010 We are using Office 365 ProPlus. If I manually open the CSV file in Excel application using Data->From Text and select UTF-8 format, the excel shows all the special characters. Therefore I can confirm that it is not doing the character conversion properly only when doing this via PS code. Can you tell me how I should troubleshoot this please?

Comment: Which special characters?

Comment: @js2010 All special characters like bullet point, long dash etc. I found another clue. I opened a plain Excel application and went to 'Data'->'From Text', browsed and opened the excel file from there.. It then processes the excel file with all the special characters! So only when I double click the excel file, it ruins all the special characters. So definitely something to do with the Excel application settings. Could it be macro related etc.?

Comment: What version of powershell?  It all works for me as long as the file isn't utf8 no bom.  You can check it in notepad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251058/discussion-between-user2574948-and-js2010).